# Difference between "regüeldo" and "eructo"

Tags: vocabulario, méxico, sinónimos

Both translate as burp or belch. Although each might have other connotations as well, I am only interested in the Spanish for a burp. What's the difference and if it's just dialectical, which one of the two is preferred in your country (I am more keen on Latin America or Mexico)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"regüeldo" is a kind of burp with odor, and is generally more disgusting. 
Burp is translated as "eructo" wich is more common here in Spain.

Comment: Really! The odor bit is interesting since none of the dictionaries mention that. Is this connotation specific to Spain?

Comment: Seems not. RAE (Real Academia de la lengua Española : Royal Academy of Spanish Language) mentions it as "releasing the gases from the stomach". As for common use, "eructo" is the common word, when "regüeldo" is less used.

Comment: I've never heard regüeldo in Mexico.

Comment: It's important to mention that "regüeldo" is not used in México. While "eructar" is the most correct and common, we also use "repetir".

Answer (score 3):

The 'Diccionario de la Real Academia' defines
[eructar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G4DIP8Q) (the verb from which 'eructo' comes)

> 1. intr. Expeler con ruido por la boca los gases del estómago.

[regoldar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VjWD0tu) (the verb from which 'regüeldo' comes)

> 1. intr. **Eructar** los gases del estómago.

So they are synonyms.

Comment: Great +1. Until today I didn't know _regüeldo_ nor _regoldar_. In hispanoamerica we always use _eructo/eructar_

Answer (score 2):

The difference is merely dialectical. I have used both and I have never inferred any nuance concerning odour. "Regüeldo" is much less frequent (although in my homeland, Zaragoza, Aragón is preferred although Aragonese Spanish has a knack for expletives) and, according to Cervantes through his most celebrated character, Don Quixote, much more offensive to the ear and, thus, condemned to be ostracized. Five centuries later, it joyfully survives at least in some regions. If you want to sound polite, always use "eructo". If you use "regüeldo", people will probably think you're the kind of person who indulges in and even enjoys the action itself.